# ASP.NET C# bind XML data to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Sorry if this question has already been asked, I am having a hard time finding an answer.

I am using ASP.NET C# GridView to bind data from an XML file. However, the data will only bind to the GridView if I remove the root <BookCollection> element. Is there any way to keep this and still bind the nested data?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BookCollection>
   <collection>
      <Books>
         <id>1</id>
         <bookName>The Bible</bookName>
         <unitprice>50</unitprice>
         <quantity>1</quantity>
      </Books>
   </collection>
</BookCollection>
```

C# Code

```
DataSet ds= new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("XML file path"));
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have tried manually using the <asp:BoundField DataField="id"/> in the GridView, still no luck.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the `Books`, then you can achieve with this,

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Books"];
```